# When object property in ObservableCollection changed, notify another property, CommunityToolkit Mvvm

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, maui

Class definition:

```
public partial class Pozycje: ObservableObject
{
   [ObservableProperty] private bool _ok;
   [ObservableProperty] private string _name;
   [ObservableProperty] private decimal _qty;
   [ObservableProperty] private decimal _val;
}
```

Collection and property definition:

```
public decimal Suma => Pozycja.Where(x => x.Ok).Sum(x=>x.Val+x.Qty);

private ObservableCollection<Pozycje> _poz;
public ObservableCollection<PozycjaObservable> Poz
{
    get => _poz;
    set
    {
      _poz = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Suma));
   }
}
```

In Xaml:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Suma}"/>
```

When I change "Poz" collection item property "Ok" Suma don't update.

Comment: Does object change?  The object could be changing but the view doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 1):

`Poz`s setter is only called when `Poz` is assigned, NOT when items are added/removed

if you want to update `Suma` when an item is added or removed from `Poz`, you need to use `Poz`s `CollectionChanged` event

```
Poz.CollectionChanged += {
  OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Suma));
}
```

Comment: I want to Update Suma when property in object that belongs to ObservableCollection changed, not when item is added or removed.

Comment: then you will need to add a `PropertyChanged` handler to each instance of `Pozycje` in the collection

Comment: Pozycje is an ObservableObject, and every property is [ObservableProperty]

Comment: that means that `Pozycje` will fire an event every time a property is changed.  You still have to do something to make `Suma` respond to that change.

Comment: I believe you have a typo it should be `+= (sender, args) => {`